# I am trying to draw on a canvas and store the draw data in firebase in order to show drawing in real time

Tags: canvas, vector, firebase, paperjs

Is there any way to store the drawings in firebase as a vector function in order to use less data?

In other words, I do not want to store each point but I want to store one updating function. Here is a demo that I am using for help. 
http://blog.cryptoguru.com/2014/11/frp-using-rxjs-and-firebase.html

Comment: please include what you have tried already

Comment: To be clear, you are want to store a function to define a vector i.e. r = f(t),g(t) instead of discreet points (x,y)?

Comment: yes. I am using the code from the above link. I would like to ues a single function that updates in order to draw on the canvas. For every time the mouse is down and then dragged, it would create a new line that updates in real time according to the changing  vector function stored in the database. thanks

Comment: and you are not using paper's  `exportJSON()` because?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can get there from here:  Firebase isn't going to provide any computational functionality, so that will have to be done at the app level. It will however, store the data about the components of the vector or even a textual representation of the function.

It also depends on if you want to have live feedback or just store/retrieve an existing set of vectors.

So for a simple example, say we want to draw a circle with it's origin at the center and represented by a vector function r(t) = (cos t, sin t). We have a canvas that we mouse down at point 1,1, then move the mouse to 2,2 and then 3,3.

data structure could be something like this

```
object_0
    function: r(t) = (cos t, sin t)
    mousedown:
       pointX: 1
       pointY: 1
    mouseup:
       pointX: 3
       pointY: 3
```

With that data we would know the design of object_0; starting location of the circle and it's size (obviously the radius could just be stored as well instead of the actual mouseup point)

As mentioned above, firebase won't do any computations, but you could read in the function and act on it according to the data in mousedown and mouseup.

If you want to act on intermediary points, say as the mouse is being dragged, you could store those in the node as well, observing it, so as the mouse is moved clients would see it move in real-time as well.

If you don't want to store points (the starting point may be a requirement?). Then an string representation of the vector at each point could be stored (cos t, sin t).

As a side note, depending on the scope, discreet points may actually take less space.

Comment: Great answer, Jay! We have a drawing app for Android that stores the vector/segment data in the way you describe.  https://github.com/firebase/AndroidDrawing